# Tweepy Set-up for twitter API access

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm working on getting my twitter API set up but I cant get it to run at all... I have watched all the tutorials I can find it it looks like I'm doing everything the same way.

```
import tweepy
#both lines 3 and 4 should be entered as strings
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(XXXXXX, XXXXX)
auth.set_access_token(XXXXX, XXXXXX)
#calling API
api = tweepy.API(auth)
#fetching statuses
statuses = api.home_timeline()
for status in statuses:
    print(status.user.screen_name)
```

I noticed when I remove the section that calls the tweets it runs without issue, but I'm not sure what I am missing

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

[Screen cap of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyvMK.png)

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/v2 go through this for access api verisons

Comment: You need Elevated access (free) to use the home timeline API which from v1.1